# How to Call a Method From Another Class in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a Quick Quesiton and I need Help. My Question is that I have created 2 classes where I want to call a method "IsWin" to my Panel Class.

This is the method That I have:

**Class Name: IsWin**

```
    public class IsWin { 

 private JButton[][] slots;
 private Color playerColor = Color.red;   

 public boolean Winner(int column, int row) {

        boolean result = false;

        // horizontal      
        boolean found = false;
        int counter = 0;

        for ( int i = 0; i < slots.length; i++ ) {        
          if ( slots[i][row].getBackground().equals(playerColor)) { 

            counter++;

            // win 
            if ( found == true ) {            
              if ( counter == 4 ) {               
                result = true;
                break;
              }
            }
            else {            
              found = true;
            }
          }

          // reset counter
          else {          
            if ( found == true ) {            
              counter = 0;
            }          
            found = false;
          }
        }
```

This is the Class where I want to Call the Method

**This is my Panel Class: connectFourPanel**

```
    private class clikMeButtonListener implements ActionListener{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {      

   if (event.getSource() == clickMeOne 
         || event.getSource() == clickMeTwo
         || event.getSource() == clickMeThree
         || event.getSource() == clickMeFour
         || event.getSource() == clickMeFive
         || event.getSource() == clickMeSix
         || event.getSource() == clickMeSeven
      ) {

     int lastEmptyIdx = -1;

     for ( int i = 0; i < slots[column].length; i++ ) {          
       if ( slots[column][i].getBackground() != Color.white ) {

         break;
       }
       else {            
         lastEmptyIdx = i;
       }
     }

     if ( lastEmptyIdx != -1 ) {          
       slots[column][lastEmptyIdx].setBackground(playerColor);

       if ( IsWin.contains(column, lastEmptyIdx) ) {

         String message = playerColor == Color.red ? " Player One Won!" : " Player Two Won!";
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, " Results ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

         System.exit(0);            
       }

       else {     
         playerColor = playerColor == Color.red ? Color.yellow : Color.red; 

         // assuming that Color.yellow is for computer player
         if ( isHumanVsComputer && playerColor == Color.yellow ) {               
           doComputerMove();
         }
       }      
     }
   } 
 }
```

**NOTE THIS IS NOT MY FULL CODE**

**UDPATE**: This is what I have in my Panel class..

```
IsWin myIsWin =  new IsWin();
myIsWin.Winner(column, row);
```

Comment: Is it a method or a class?

Answer (score 3):

You can make the method which you want to call from another class `static` and then call it using `<ClassName>.<MethodName>`.

For Example,

```
public class Foo {
    public static void foobar() {
        /* Your Code Here */
    }
}
```

Now, you can access this method using `Foo.foobar();` as follows:

```
public class Panel {
    public void someMethod() {
        Foo.foobar();
        /* Your Code Here */
    }
}
```

Comment: Waitt So... All the Winner Checking code goes into the new class i have created but i rite <className>.<methodName>? Corrent? yes or No

Comment: @JainamPatel Assuming `Winner` is your method name, you'll have to make it static as follows: `public static boolean Winner(int column, int row)`. Now, you can just do `IsWin.Winner(...)` from a method of `Panel` class.

Comment: Hey I did that But There are Alot of Error:  This is what I have Done: IsWin.Winner(); Error: Syntax error on token "Winner", Identifier expected after this token

Comment: @JainamPatel Where are the two parameters? Your method takes two parameters but here you are not passing them! It should be something like: `IsWin.Winner(2,3);`

Comment: But what Should go Inside the Bracket --> (). would it be column and row?

Comment: @JainamPatel Yes, Obviously! That is how you have defined the method in the first place right?

Comment: I have tried that But it says to remove the brackets.... and gives me other error in the Winner Methoddd...

Comment: @JainamPatel What do you mean by *" it says to remove the brackets"*? Can you include the error trace in your question?

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "(", delete 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token ")", delete 
  this token                                                                                                                                                                                                           Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field slots                                  Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field playerColor                               Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field slots

Comment: @JainamPatel Well looks like you are referring `slots` and `playerColor` inside `Winner()` method. You can make them static too or access the `Winner()` method by using a new object of `IsWin` class as Xoce suggested. Also, can you post the code on how you are calling the `Winner()` method?

Comment: I have posted the Full code for both the classes and the only i have added is what **Etienne GT** suggested.. But That Doesn;t Work...

Comment: @JainamPatel Well you should **Go and Lean Basic Java** first. Nobody will be fixing your mess here. The responses you got are for the problem you asked and not for the errors in your existing code. Good Luck fixing it!

Answer (score 0):

you will need to declare  an object of the class **IsWin** in the **Panel** class and to that instance call the method `Winner()`

## Example:

```
IsWin myIsWin =  new IsWin....

myIsWin.Winner(0, 0);
```

Comment: I did what u suggest but give me error...................................................: 'Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "(", delete 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token ")", delete 
  this token'

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the IsWin Object and access the Winner method.
For Example:

```
    IsWin iw = new IsWin();
    if ( iw.winner(column, lastEmptyIdx) ) {
        String message = playerColor == Color.red ? " Player One Won!" : " Player Two Won!";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, " Results ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        System.exit(0);            
    }
```

Comment: Now I did What U told me to but Now it gives me error... Like my game is not running properly... I am making a Connect 4 Game... so like would u like helping me out with it????????/